# Selecting with 2 JOINs to get a count and a concatenated string

Tags: sql

3 tables:
items(item_id, ...)
tags(item_id, tag_name)
downloads(item_id, ...)

How do I select a single item together with the number of occurrences of this item in the downloads table and all tag_name values associated with that item?

Tried:

```
SELECT 
    ...,
    COUNT(downloads.item_id) AS download_count,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name SEPARATOR ":") AS tags
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN tags ON items.item_id = tags.item_id 
LEFT JOIN downloads ON items.item_id  = downloads.item_id 
WHERE items.item_id = 123
```

Doesn't work. Returns the tags multiple times. As many times as the occurrences of the item in the "downloads" table are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not surprised you're getting multiples, because you have created a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) between `tags` and `downloads`.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    ...,
    COUNT(DISTINCT downloads.download_id) AS download_count,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.tag_name SEPARATOR ":") AS tags
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN tags ON items.item_id = tags.item_id 
LEFT JOIN downloads ON items.item_id  = downloads.item_id 
WHERE items.item_id = 123
```

However, I'd recommend doing this in two queries.  You don't have to do everything in a single query, and sometimes it's faster to run two simpler queries:

```
SELECT 
    ...,
    COUNT(*) AS download_count,
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN downloads ON items.item_id  = downloads.item_id 
WHERE items.item_id = 123

SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name SEPARATOR ":") AS tags
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN tags ON items.item_id = tags.item_id 
WHERE items.item_id = 123
```

Comment: This answers 2 questions of mine as I was also wondering whether I should use 2 queries instead of 1 to get the data in question. Thank you!